# Exposing an object's members in the scope of a different class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to expose the public member variables and methods of an object into the scope of a class? For instance,

```
class A {
   val foo
   fun bar() {
      
   }
}

class B(
   val a : A
) {
   using a // I want something like this statement
   
   ... etc
}
```

In this example, I would want to be able to access a's methods like this

```
val a = A()
val b = B(a = a)

val c = b.foo
b.bar()
```

This might seem silly, but I am building an Android app and it would make it a lot easier to pass dependencies down a UI tree this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Kotlin feature called [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html):

```kotlin
open class A {
   val foo: Int = 42
   fun bar() {
       
   }
}

class B(val a : A): A by a {}

fun main() {
    val a = A()
    val b = B(a = a)

    println(b.foo)
    b.bar()
}
```

However, note that this will error with "Only interfaces can be delegated to" on `B`'s declaration. This means that `A` must be an interface for this feature to work. A workaround:

```kotlin
interface A {
   val foo: Int
   fun bar() {
       
   }
}

// Create an intermediate class that implements A
class AA : A {
    override val foo: Int = 42
    
    override fun bar() {}
}

class B(val a : A): A by a {}

fun main() {
    val a = AA()      // Instantiates `AA` instead of `A`
    val b = B(a = a)

    println(b.foo)    // Outputs 42
    b.bar()
}
```

Comment: Okay, that seems really similar to what I want, but it's unfortunate that it only works for interfaces. I was hoping to be able to keep wrapping additional functionality by nesting more and more objects inside each other, without having to access the methods like `e.d.c.b.a.foo`. I guess Kotlin doesn't have this feature though.

Comment: *without making a new interface for each class.

Comment: Regarding the "accessing the methods like `e.d.c.b.a.foo` there is syntactic sugar that can help remove the prefix: `with()` or `run()` see https://typealias.com/start/kotlin-scopes-and-scope-functions/